# h5py writing a hdf file , question about dimension

Tags: python, h5py

I created a new file whose handle is fw.

```
fw.create_dataset('grp1/grp2/grp2/varname',data=arr)
```

The groups are created before this command. `arr` is a `numpy` `array` with
dimensions `(2,3)`.
The file is created successfully. However, the dimensions are named `phony_0`,
and `phony_1`. How do I change them to say `m` and `n` ?

In general how does one create dimensions within a group and then associate
variables with them?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate question (by the same user): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978389/h5py-how-to-rename-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like

```
dataset.dims[0].label = 'm'
dataset.dims[1].label = 'n'
```

But really, it's all in the official docs: http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dims.html